# Java: Improving speed of a reader program

Tags: java, csv

Hey so I am working on this program that reads CSV files and I need to make a method which can return one entire column on values.

Currently I do it like this:

```
List<String> data = new LinkedList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < getRowCount(); i++){
         data.add(getRow(i).get(column));
    }
```

Where getRow() is this:

```
List<String> data = new LinkedList<>();
    String column;

    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
            bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
        column = bufferedReader.readLine();
        for(String col: column.split(columnSeparator.toString())){
            data.add(col);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and it works. But the flaw is, if there are too many columns in a file it takes way too long. It takes 27 secondso n 7500 lines and 9 columns. Over 10 minutes on 35000 lines and 16 columns. Do you know how could I make it faster?

Comment: Do you realize you're processing the entire file up to the *i*th row for each iteration? Also, what's `column`?

Comment: don't remake your buffered reader each time.

Comment: @shmosel Yea it eventually hit me thanks :D column is argument of getColumn method. Basically the number of column I want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is the following:

1. Prepare to read the file (Creating ReaderObject, ...), read first line
2. Prepare to read the file, read first line, read second line
3. Preapre to read the file, read first line, read second line, read third line

.. And so on.
Apparently this is not very efficient (Your doing stuff in O(n²), with n = number of lines).

You could improve your code vastly, if you do it something like this:

1. Prepare to read the file
2. Read the first line
3. Read the second line

... And so on.
So first read all the lines at once:

```
List<String> lines = new LinkedList<>();

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        lines.add(line);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can then iterate over the lines to split them into columns and extract the data you're interested in:

```
List<String> data = new LinkedList<>();

for(String line : lines)
     data.add(line.split(columnSeparator.toString())[column]);
```

Of course this still needs a little bit of error handling :)

Comment: How is your solution so much faster than this? for(int i = 0; i < getRowCount(); i++){
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                columns = line.split(columnSeparator.toString());
                data.add(columns[column]);

Yours takes barely a second while mine takes 5 minutes. What is so bad about my solution?

Comment: Ok I have the problem. It is the for cycle. But why? :D

Comment: I guess getRowCount() takes a lot of time. As you call it each loop cycle this function can have a huge effect on overall performance. What does this method? For improvement, call getRowCount() once in the beginning and save it in a variable, then use this variable for your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read the file once:

```
List<String> getColumn(int column) {
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        List<String> data = new LinkedList<>();
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            String cols[] = line.split(columnSeparator.toString());
            data.add(cols[column]);
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
        return data;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try this

```
DataType<T> listRef = getRowCount();
for(int i = 0; i < listRef.size(); i++)
    {
         data.add(getRow(i).get(column));
    }
```

getRowCount is executed every single time when you call it in a for statement and you would eventually get all the rows but internally I believe that calling makes it go and execute that method getRowCount().size() times and you probably don't want to read a file that many times

Comment: Good point, but `getRow(i)` is equally problematic, if not more so.

Comment: Sorry I din't notice that I looked at that statement and figured that It was something do do with file reads (I've done the same thing once ;P) any way thanks for letting me know